# Given a population of fish with exponential growth, what is the optimal strategy for fishing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, recreational-mathematics, dynamic-programming, optimal-control

Suppose we have a population of fish, say $10000$, with an exponential growth each year of $30\%$.

If we want to collect as many fish as possible in, say 10 years, a natural question to ask is:

> What is the optimal number of fish to catch each year?

Mathematically speaking, we have a sequence defined by:

> $a_{n+1}=1.3 \cdot (1-k_n)a_n$
>
> $a_0=10000$

where $k_n$ is the percentage of fish we want to collect in the $n$th year. We want to choose $k_1, k_2, k_3, \dots, k_n$ to maximize $a_{10}$.

Also, $k$ is capped at some number. Let it be $k \leq 0.05$.

I think this problem is quite economically relevant, but can't think of any optimal solution for it.

Comment: Leave the fish alone for the first $n-1$ years. Collect as many as you want in the last year.

Comment: I have thought of that too, but can't rigorously prove it. We should definitely collect all the fish as many as we can in the last year, but could it be better if we collect some fishes in the previous years instead of letting it grow ? Also what if we place a bound on k, say k should be less than 15% ?

Comment: There is a complication because of the time value of money. It can be "good" strategy to overharvest and invest the money.  Particularly with more realistic rate of growth figures.

Comment: Any fish you collect now is 1.3 less fish you can collect the next year, so there is no advantage to collecting early. Now if you have a cap on the percentage of fish you can collect in a year, that makes it more interesting.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Now when I think about it, the problem is trivial if k is not capped. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deciding how much to fish, let us decide how much **not** to fish. Let $x_k$ be the number of fish at year $k$ and let $u_k \in [0.95,1]$ be the percentage of fish not to fish at year $k$. Hence,

$$x_{k+1} = 1.3 \, x_k \, u_k $$

and

$$\begin{array}{rl} x_1 &= 1.3 \, x_0 \, u_0\\ x_2 &= 1.3 \, x_1 \, u_1 = 1.3^2 \, x_0 \, u_1 \, u_0\\ x_3 &= 1.3 \, x_2 \, u_2 = 1.3^3 \, x_0 \, u_2 \, u_1 \, u_0\\ &\vdots\\ x_N &= 1.3^N \, x_0 \displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{N-1} u_k\end{array}$$

As $x_0$ is given, maximizing $x_N$ is equivalent to maximizing the product $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{N-1} u_k$. Hence,

$$u_0 = u_1 = \cdots = u_{N-1} = 1$$

In other words, the **optimal fishing strategy is not to fish at all**! It would probably be wise to update the objective function.

Comment: You are right. I didn't give much thought to this question. The objective function should be, according to your notation: $\sum_{i=1}^n(1-u_i)x_i$. Thanks for your answer !